# Turn NULL to NA in R

Tags: r, dataframe, nan, missing-data

I m trying to convert all the NULL values in my dataset to NA. In short

#### Explanation of question

My data set looks like below:

[image]

One thing that I noticed though is that when I try to find the number of empty values it shows the number of NA values in my dataset not including the NULL values. I would like to convert the NULL values to NA in order to remove them.

So I counted the number of missing values in my complete dataset then in the columns as

```
> dim(raw_data)
[1] 80983    16
> # Count missing values in entire data set
> table(is.na(raw_data))

  FALSE    TRUE 
1247232   48496 
> # Count na 's column wise
> na_count <-sapply(raw_data, function(y) sum(length(which(is.na(y)))))
> na_count <- data.frame(na_count)
> na_count
                     na_count
Merchant_Id                 1
Tran_Date                   1
Military_Time               1
Terminal_Id_Key             1
Amount                      1
Card_Amount_Paid            1
Merchant_Name               1
Town                        1
Area_Code                   1
Client_ID               48481
Age_Band                    1
Gender_code                 1
Province                    1
Avg_Income_3M               1
Value_Spent                 1
Number_Spent                1
```

As you can see it does not show the NULL as NA so I tried to convert it as:

```
> # Turn Null to NA
> temp_data <- raw_data
> 
> temp_data[temp_data == ''] = NA

Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I also tried

```
> # Turn Null to NA
> temp_data <- raw_data
> temp_data[temp_data == 'NULL'] = NA
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

But I am getting the error above. This was followed by the last one below (which was better because I did not have an error but I still got NULL values in my data set).

```
> raw_data[is.null(raw_data)] <- NA
> table(is.na(raw_data))

  FALSE    TRUE 
1247232   48496
```

Could you perhaps suggest ways to deal with this error?

I also tried to get rid of the date and got this different error when I once again tried to remove the NULL values:

```
> df <- raw_data
> 
> df1 <- transform(df, date = as.Date(df$Tran_Date), time = format(df$Tran_Date, "%T"))
> 
> df1[df1 == NULL] = NA
Error in matrix(if (is.null(value)) logical() else value, nrow = nr, dimnames = list(rn,  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

Comment: If `NULL` is a character string.  `raw_data[] <- lapply(raw_data, as.character);raw_data[raw_data == "NULL"] <- NA`

Comment: and if its not `raw_data[is.null(raw_data)] <- NA`

Comment: If your data is imported from a file and you want "NULL" set to NA from the start, you could define `na.strings`, e.g. `rawData <- read.table("rawdatafile.csv", na.strings = c("NA", "NULL"), header=TRUE)`

Comment: My data is downloaded as a tsv off github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue. Instead of changing the NULL values to NA. I imported the values in from the github account as NA values.

I added

`na = c("","NA","NULL",NULL)`

to my importing argument `read.table` or `read_tsv` from `readr` package. This then did the trick and changed my NULL values to NA.